# I want to call a function of MainActivity from Drawer button

Tags: android, model-view-controller, kotlin, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to call a function of Activity from drawer?

Let say: Main Activity is opened. There is a function displayImage() in it. I want to call it from drawer.

Comment: make that function public static. can call it by doing MainActivity.displayImage();

Comment: @DroiDev That's a horrible idea.  If it actually doesn't require Activity member variables, it shouldn't be on MainActivity.  And if it does, it can't be static

Comment: displayImage() is using context of MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please go through the bellow code snippet**
drawer.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/u_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/lead_leader"
            android:title="User name" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/logout"
            android:title="Logout" />

    </group>
</menu>
**after that add bellow code in  your Mainactivity.java file**

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lead_profile, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.logout) {

            //call your other method according navigation drawer item with other id in a different if block.

 ///call your function here
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: It will add an item in navigation drawer menu and when you click on that item the the desired function would be call plz let me know if you are facing any problem

Comment: does onCreateOptionsMenu() not called on menu options but not on Navigation drawer.
I asked for the drawer that comes from the left side and cover the activity